# Android : ActionBarSherlock : How do I use the ActionBarSherlock on older versions of Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm beginning development on an app and I set the target to Android 2.2. can i use actionbarsherlock in my app?

I added below code in pom file :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>r7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

but my app does not run in my phone with android 2.2 and i have this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
```

but when i set theme one of these appear error that no source found!
I don't know how can i fix this, any body have an idea?

Comment: How is your application tag in your manifest file? How is the theme parameter?

Comment: import sherlock library then right click your project>android>add>select library>ok

Comment: @Ketan: i add sherlock library in pom file, i use maven library.

Comment: @ElhamGdz sorry I don't know what is maven as I never used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import SherLock Library and add blow code in styles.xml and AndroidManifest.xml

styles.xml

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
       ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
          ...
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: i added these codes but when i run app this error will appear: "android-apt-compiler:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar'."

Comment: then use <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock" />

Comment: again have error: "android-apt-compiler: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock'."

Comment: have you added ActionBarSherLock Library in your projects?
add Library project.properties eg . android.library.reference.1="ActionBarSherLock Library path"

Comment: I use maven library, It is not enough? should i add library in my project?

Comment: it means import the library? are you sure?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42940/discussion-between-kanaiya-and-elham-gdz)